# What's the difference between 両方 and 双方?

Tags: words

What's the difference between 両方 and 双方? I am definitely more acquainted with 両方, so I guess it is used for a wider variety of things, but could anyone tell me the specifics of what they can or cannot pertain to?

Answer (score 4):

I think your guess is right that `両方` has a wider meaning. `双方` means "mutual sides," so it is used only when the two objects are in some relation to one another. You can use either one when there is some relation between the two objects (people):

> 被害者と加害者の両方から事情を聞く
> 'hear about the case from both the victim and the perpetrator'
>
> 被害者と加害者の双方から事情を聞く
> 'hear about the case from both the victim and the perpetrator sides'

but when there is no particular relation between the two objects, it is awkward to use`双方`.

> 田中と鈴木の両方から授業のノートを借りる
> 'borrow class notes from both Tanaka and Suzuki'
>
> ?? 田中と鈴木の双方から授業のノートを借りる
> 'borrow class notes from both Tanaka and Suzuki sides'